# Creating Function Utilizing Conditional Counting

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I want to develop a function to automate the process of grade analyzing.

In one column, there is the number of tutoring hours a student had and in the next column is his or her grade.

For three groups, I have to count the number of As (A+s and A-s), Bs (B+s and A-s), Cs, Ds, Fs, Ws and calculate the GPA of each. The groups are those who had 6 or more hours, those who had no hours, and the total number of those who had tutoring.

Is it possible to create a simple function in R, such as **Grades(Hours,Mark)**, similar to the **Summary()** function, that would print three categories with the following information for each:

1. Number of students with any type(As include A-s, As, and A+s,etc.) of A, B, C, D, F, W
2. Calculate GPA: (4*A+3*B+2*C+1*D+0*F+0*W)/(A + B+ C + D+ F - W)

Is this even possible to do in R? Where would I start?

Thanks.

Comment: Start by posting a sample dataset.

Comment: `Hours=c(0,5,6,10,0);Grades=c("F","A-","A","A+","C-")`

Comment: Please learn to use the edit function.

Comment: Sorry about that! I figured it out now.

Answer (score 0):

```
> Hours=c(0,5,6,10,0);Grades=c("F","A-","A","A+","C-") 
> grpHrs <- Hours >= 6
> table( substr(Grades, 1,1), grpHrs)
   grpHrs
    FALSE TRUE
  A     1    2
  C     1    0
  F     1    0
```

Hard to know what sort of GPA calculation is needed since its clear that these are different students. If these were all from the same student then:

```
grdABCDFW <- substr(Grades,1,1)



sum( 4* (grdABCDFW=="A")+
     3*(grdABCDFW=="B")+
     2*(grdABCDFW=="C")+ 
     1*(grdABCDFW=="D")+ 
     0*(grdABCDFW=="F")+ 0*(grdABCDFW=="W") )/
                 length(Grades[ !is.na(Grades)] )
#[1] 2.8
```

To your comment. Perhaps:

```
Hours.time=function(Hours, Grades, cutpt){  
                 grpHrs <- Hours >= cutpt
                 tbl <- table( substr(Grades,1,1), grpHrs)
                 colnames(tbl) <- c(  paste("Fewer than ", cutpt),
                                     paste( cutpt, "or more") )
                  tbl }
 Hours.time(Hours, Grades,6)
 #-------
   grpHrs
    Fewer than  6 6 or more
  A             1         2
  C             1         0
  F             1         0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That works perfectly! Is there any way to put this in a joint function? I did the one, `Hours.6=function(Hours,Grades,grpHrs){grpHrs<-Hours>=6;table(substr(Grades,1,1),grpHrs)}'but how could I do it so that all I have to write is Hours and then it gives two tables, one with >=6 hours and one with 0 hours? Cheers!

Comment: Note: Your editor is inserting non-printable characters. You should consider using a standard text editor.